# Make Sleep/Hibernate Timer depend on CPU-user / download?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate, cpu-usage

I am usually letting my (Lenovo, Win 7 Ultimate x64) laptop go to sleep after 15 mins, which is just perfect for me. With one exception:

**Is there a tool or other tweak, that would prevent going to sleep if CPU load is consistently over 50% or download is above a certain amount of MB per minute?** (that way, tiny "pings" and "downloads" would not prevent sleep, also serious up/downloading and (in my case:) image rendering  would keep the machine awake until the job is done... then let it go to sleep.

Of course I can keep changing the power settings, but I am kinda lazy. And I am not keen on getting up at 3a.m. to tell my machine, that it's done and time to sleep. (Yes, various FTP and rendering tools have a shutdown-when-done option, but this is too specific for me)

*Would be a darn useful feature (and add environmental friendlyness) for a not that small range of users, to have "additional sleep criteria", wouldn't it?* And if M$ is not gonna do it, have a tool that simulates a click or mousemove to keep the computer awake as long as needed as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

[Shutdown Timer](http://www.sinvise.net/home/projects/software/shutdown-timer) is a really good app that lets you customize your shutdown in all kinds of manners.

Comment: I tried and bought Shutdown Timer that but finally I use NoSleep: http://www.computerbase.de/forum/showthread.php?t=770730 You can easily setup global CPU and Network limits. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

> download is above a certain amount of
>   MB per minute

http://sourceforge.net/projects/coffee-sc/

Works for Win7 and Vista only, early alpha stage... I need feedback :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if there is a way to do the measuring of the CPU load, however if you can do timings then I'd suggest using a bat file with something like the following:

```
@echo off
sleep 900000
SHUTDOWN -S -F -T 30 -C "Shutting down in 30 seconds."
```

This would wait 15 minutes and then shut down the computer in 30 seconds.